# Xcode 4: how do I use an int in two different classes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdk, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

First of all sorry for my I english.

I'm creating an app that counts the times you touch up inside a button. The app is divided by a UITabBarController: in the first view (class: ViewController) there is a button and a label that displays the value of an "int" (int counter;), the thing is that I want to set a maximum number, so when you have touched the button 50 times, an alertView appears. I want to make this maximum number flexible so you can adjust it by a slider that is in the second view of the tabBar.

Here is the code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    int counter;
    IBOutlet UILabel *counterLabel;
}

-(IBAction)counter:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Reset:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)counter:(id)sender{
    if (counter < end)  // in spite of end, I want to put Max (declared in AjustesView.h)
    {
        counter = counter+1;
        counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Jugador1];

    }else
    {
        UIAlertView *alerta = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alerta!" message:@"Ha llegado a 100 cliks" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alerta show];
        [alerta release];
    }
}

-(IBAction)Reset:(id)sender{
    counter = 0;
    counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counter];
}
```

**AjustesView.h**

```
    @interface AjustesView : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UISlider *maxSlider;
    IBOutlet UILabel *maxLabel;
    int max;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *maxSlider;

-(IBAction)AdjustmentOfMaximum:(id)sender;

@end
```

**AjustesView.m**

```
#import "AjustesView.h"

@implementation AjustesView

@synthesize maxSlider;

-(IBAction)AdjustmentOfMaximum:(id)sender{
    max = self.maxSlider.value;
    maxLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", max];
}
```

IB file is .xib not storyboard
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is store your int value in your application's AppDelegate and synthesize it as a property. Whenever you want to update or get the value you just need to get the value from AppDelegate like so

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"



..

//whenever you want to access the value or update the value
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myCounter = newvalue;
```

Comment: would it work on my case?
because newValue is equal to the value of the slider that is in the second view

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a user-defined preference. For that, use `NSUserDefaults`

Use the below methods to set and get an integer from `NSUserDefaults`.

```
-(void)setInt:(int)myInt{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //To set a value
    [prefs setInteger:myInt ForKey:@"myInt"];
    [prefs syncronize];
}

-(int)getInt{
//to get a value
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"myInt"];
}
```

[This is the Apple NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: where Should I write each thing? I'm not an advanced programmer. thx

Comment: sorry, but I don't know how to do that :(
I'm writing it in view controller.m (look at my post)
thanks and sorry an other time